# Install Performance Tools for SQL Server 2008

Tags: installation, profiler, ssms

We have SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition here.
I have been using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 for connecting to our Data Source - this has been working fine for the last year.

When I first got here, I found an article on this site that stated that to install Management Studio, you just down the SQL Server Express 2005/2008 installer. Once installed, it will give you access to features according to the SQL Server version of the Data Source (this worked a treat).

I now need to use SQL Profiler, but it isn't present in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.
Through searching online, I apparently need to tick the "Management Tools - Complete" option - but this option is not present on the installer.

I am using SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe to attempt to install this but the feature is not present, it only has "Management Tools - Basic" available.

There does not seem to be a way to point the installer at my Data Source, so that it can see that it will be used with an Enterprise licensed server.

I have tried downloading various versions, but still the "Complete" option is missing.

Is there an installer that I can download with this option enabled, or do I have to ask my support services team to speak to Microsoft to provide a special installation program for me to get this facility?

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MS does not provide the SqlProfiler with Express versions of Sql Server.  I have been looking for a profiler alternative myself, found ExpressProfiler on Codeplex but its a bit crude and not very configurable.  This one works quite nicely: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784905/Real-time-Tracing-With-SQL-Server-Express